# Running find, grep and awk script

Tags: linux, awk

I am using find to search for file. then I pass this file as argument for grep. I want to run awk script on each result? How can I do this ?

so lets say, find returns 5 files, grep on each file return 15 lines and on these 15 lines, i want to run awk script.

I tried following but it error out

```
find . -type f -name test.log | xargs grep -A 15 "Data starts now" | xargs awk -f postprocess.awk
```

can anybody suggest anything wrong with syntax ?

Lets say file test1.log is

```
num1 104
num2 434
Num3 572
Data starts now
num1 04
num2 34
Num3 72
```

Lets say file test2.log is

```
num1 203
num2 135
Num3 098
Data starts now
num1 17
num2 33
Num3 89
```

Lets say file test3.log is

```
num1 924
num2 834
Num3 532
Data starts now
num1 34
num2 63
Num3 89
```

postprocess.awk is

```
{
if($1=="num1")
   {
   num1_value =$2;
   }

if($1=="num2")
   {
   num2_value =$2;
   }


if($1=="num3")
   {
   num3_value =$2;
   }



}

END {
mult=num1_value*num2_value;
print "Multiplication is " mult;
}
```

if I run

```
find . -type f -name "test*.log" -exec grep -A15 "Data starts now" {} + | awk -f postprocess.awk
```

I should have got 3 output but get only 1 line with wrong result

```
Multiplication is 0
```

Comment: I provided [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61976067/207248) which does ***everything*** using GNU awk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU `awk` you can do ***everything*** in one line:

```
$ awk 'c{c--;a[$1]=$2} /Data starts now/{c=15} \
    ENDFILE{m=1;c=0;for(i in a){m*=a[i]}print FILENAME": Multiplication is "m}' test*.log
test1.log: Multiplication is 9792
test2.log: Multiplication is 49929
test3.log: Multiplication is 190638
```

#### Explanation

```
awk '
  c{                       # if c is non-zero (c is 0 when script is 1st ran)
     c--                   # decrement c
     a[$1]=$2              # Create a hash-map with $1 as the key and $2 as the value
   }
  /Data starts now/{c=15}  # When regex matches, set c to 15
  ENDFILE{                 # True when the last record of a file has been read (gawk only)
    m=1                    # Set m to one so multiplication doesnt return 0
    c=0                    # Set c to 0 in case file has less than 15 lines after match
    for(i in a){           # For each key/value pair...
      m*=a[i]              # Multiply them together and store result in m
    }
    print FILENAME": Multiplication is "m}
' test*.log
```

Answer (score 1):

To run `grep` and `awk` on each individual file found by `find`, you can use the `-exec` action and start a small shell script:

```
find . -type f -name "test*.log" -exec sh -c '
  for file; do
    grep -A15 "Data starts now" "$file" | awk -f postprocess.awk
  done
' sh {} +
```

Comment: above solution is not working..it produces only 1 output and that too wrong. I am using Cshell

Answer (score 1):

It will be clearer if you create another helper script (`postprocess.sh`)

```
for f in $*
do
   grep -A 15 "Data starts now" $f | awk -f postprocess.awk
done
```

and then run this inside the `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -name "test*.log" -exec sh postprocess.sh {} +
```